# Duda rapida de await_for

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@client.command()
async def banco(ctx):
    await ctx.send("¿Quieres atender la llamada?")
    await ctx.send("Di Si o No")

    def check(m):
        return m.content in ("si", "no")

    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)

    msg = await ctx.send("Arribando al lugar" if msg.content == "si" else "Cancelando llamada :/.")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
    await msg.edit(content='Has llegado')
```

Buenas, ¿Como se puede hacer que cuando diga "**Arribando al lugar**" y en '**Has llegado**", salga en formato embed.

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplemente crea un embed instanciando [`discord.Embed`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed), luego usa el argumento `embed` de `send` para enviarlo.

En cuanto a la edición, simplemente asigna un nuevo contenido al campo (atributo) a modificar del embed creado antes y pasa el embed de nuevo a `edit` con el argumento `embed`:

```
@client.command()
async def banco(ctx):
    await ctx.send("¿Quieres atender la llamada?")
    await ctx.send("Di Si o No")

    def check(m):
        return m.content in ("si", "no")

    msg = await client.wait_for("message", check=check)

    if msg.content == 'si':
        embed = discord.Embed(
            description="Arribando al lugar",
            color=0xca9100
            )
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        embed.description = "Has llegado"
        await asyncio.sleep(5)
        await msg.edit(embed=embed)
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            description="Cancelando llamada :/.",
            color=0xca9100
            )
        msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este caso solo he usado el campo `description`, la clase `Embed` y los embeds de Discord es mucho más compleja y completa, permitiendo enviar muchas más cosas (autor, icono, imagenes, videos, título, pie, enlaces, etc) como puede verse en la documentación de la calse enlazada arriba.  Un ejemplo más completo:

```
embed = discord.Embed(
    title="Ejemplo para SOes",
    url="https://es.stackoverflow.com/",
    description="Esto es un embed de Discord",
    color=0xca9100
    )
embed.set_author(
    name="FJSevilla",
    url="https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15089/fjsevilla?tab=profile",
    icon_url="https://i.stack.imgur.com/934Lz.png?s=328&g=1"
    )
embed.add_field(
    name="Personas alcanzadas",
    value="1.2m",
    inline=False
    )
embed.add_field(
    name="Reputación",
    value="39695",
    inline=False)
embed.set_footer(text="Saludos y cuidense.... :)")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Disculpa, funciona la primera parte, pero al poner si o no, no manda el embed

Comment: Perdon, había un typo en el código, en vez de msg tenia message.... corregido, debería funcionar.

Comment: Que fue lo que importaste?